# Why won't my MBP connect to Personal Hotspot via wifi?

Tags: wifi, macos, ios, iphone, tethering

I have not been able to connect my retina Macbook Pro to my iPhone 5s Personal Hotspot since upgrading to OSX 10.10 (Yosemite).

While I can see the phone in the list of wifi APs under 
the "Personal Hotspot" sub-list, attempting to connect to it fails every time, even though the devices are only about two feet from each other.

• I attempted to "forget" the AP and re-add it, but this did not resolve the issue.

• My provider is Verizon.

[image: Failed to enable Personal Hotspot dialogue]

Comment: How many Wi-Fi networks do you see on your MacBook Pro under the Wi-Fi top menu?

Answer (score 2):

Connected my laptop to a different Hotspot device, then back to my phone. Everything seems to work now. Very strange.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please make a comment to the original wuestion if you see information which might help to avoid you to get the same problem again.